# Windows asks to install printer driver over and over

Tags: domain-controller, windows-server-2019, print-server

I have over 400 users on a 2012 DC, and a Win2019 server configured as a print server, which serves about 279 printers of varying make/model. Some users are receiving driver install messages when trying to print. Some users are also seeing, "Do you trust this printer? Windows needs to download and install a software driver from the \ps01 computer to print to FL04-Copier Canon 55601." The popup has the blue/yellow shield on the Install Driver button.

This behavior appears to be increasing in frequency. We do have a fairly large set of GPOs deployed in the environment, but so far I've not found one that might restrict installing windows drivers (I haven't finished reviewing them all).

The print server was running on Win2012, which prompted me to spin up this new 2019 instance to see if that would help. I took the old 2012 VM down and re-assigned the IP and MAC address to the new one, then had to delete and re-add the server to the DC so that we didn't have to re-map all the printers to a new share address.

Even as an admin on the DC I received #740 errors installing a printer on my own laptop, which to me is odd. We've removed and tried to re-install printers on user machines that exhibit this behavior, as well as rebooting their machines. Still the problem persists.

I'm seeing the printer server CPU and memory has a high rate of utilization, which I plan to address this weekend.

So there are a lot of variables here. Can anyone suggest a good way to diagnose this?

Comment: imho a fairly clean migration would be a better solution for this. mostly what does the event log says. moreover what exakt issues so you get?

Comment: I'm beginning to agree with your assessment. Replacing the old print server with a new one by swapping out it's IP and MAC address seems to have caused more problems than solutions. We still have occasional users that have printers going through the endless loop of asking for driver updates. removing and re-adding those printers seems the path of least resistance, although I've also seen some cases where the system will just not let you add a printer you've already deleted.

Comment: it is normal, that printers needs to be re-mapped. this should be done usually via GPO and makes the admin life easy as possible